# Blacklist filtering data for SQL Keywords

Tags: java, validation, security, sql-injection

I am trying to validate data before inserting them into the database(POSTGRESQL). The data corresponding to email, zip code etc are easily validated with the use of Apache Commons Validator. But in case of names I used this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][ a-zA-Z]{1-30}$
```

This prevents any special characters from being added as name, but it fails to prevent users from adding `DROP or GRANT` as a name. As I am using `PreparedStatement`, I didn't think it was going to be a problem but it is now required that SQL keywords shouldn't go in the db as it may lead to a *Second Order SQL Injection.*

I thought of using blacklisting all SQL keywords (surely, this will prevent Huge Grant from logging into our site. :P) but it seems that there are >64 keywords. Is this **(Blacklist filtering data for SQL Keywords)** a proper approach for **preventing Second Order SQL Injection**? What are my options?

I am using this code:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, name) VALUES (?,?,?);";
        try{
            conn=SomeStaticClass.createConnection();
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, dataBean.getUsername());
            ps.setString(2, dataBean.getPassword());
            ps.setString(3, dataBean.getName());
            ps.execute();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(ps!=null){
                    ps.close();
                }
                conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second order injection only occurs if you store the keywords in the database and then later use them in an unsafe manner. If you use prepared statements and they are properly parameterized it won't occur. Cisco have a good summary of understanding SQL injection:

http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html

Apart from your example of "Grant" there are also many such as IF, BY, IS, IN, TO that will occur very commonly in English language / names.

Comment: So I guess, there is no need for any blacklist filtering of SQL Keywords as I am using `PreparedStatement` everywhere.

Comment: You will be fine as long as anything retrieved from the database is passed to other prepared queries as parameters to the query and not concatenating anything as a string. Using columns directly in queries is also fine as well because they will always be treated as literals.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a proper approach for this kind of a situation?

No.

SQL injection happens when you assemble an SQL queries by concatenating Strings.

The "best practice" approach to preventing SQL injection is to use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with constant SQL queries that have placeholders for the parameters.  Then you use the prepared statement `set` methods to set values for each of the placeholder parameters.  This approach will guarantee that any "nasty" string parameters containing SQL keywords will be interpreted as literal strings.

---

**UPDATE** - Using `PreparedStatements` consistently should protect against second order attacks too ... assuming that you are referring to something like this:

http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/html/lesson1/les01_tm_attacks2.htm

You just need to make sure that you don't build the SQL query string from anything that could possibly be tainted.  Provided you handle any potentially tainted data using placeholders, it doesn't matter where it came from.

(Black listing SQL keywords will help to keep garbage out of your database.  But as you mentioned, it can potentially cause damage to legitimate data and impact on your system's usability.  I wouldn't do it.  It would be better to rely on good programmer discipline ... and thorough code reviews.)

Comment: I think I am using the same approach as you mentioned. I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: PreperedStatement is Java response to SQL-Injection, and safe DB communication. BUT escaping is provided by the jdbc driver, and lately there was a problem with prostgreSQL driver because it failed to meet the requirements, thus allowing for sql-Injection but it was an inciden, and should be treated like that. Plus writing a simple unit test can check driver's escaping capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

It is extreamly difficult, if not impossible, to ensure that all data in your database can be used with any script language (like SQL or HTML) without proper escaping in the future. It is impossible to distinguish between "safe" and "unsafe" characters before you now how the characters are going to be used anyway.

Trying to escape and clean all data before they are inserted into the database may lead you to belive that user-generated data in the database is "safe", which is a very dangerous belief. You can only know if the data is safe when you know how they are going to be used, and you will only know that when you actually use the data (since data in a database can live for a very long time).

The best strategy for avoiding this kind of problems is to always escape all data when you actually use them, either by using PreparedStatement like you do, properly escaping them when you use them in html, escaping them when you insert them into an email etc. etc.

I gave some examples in this answer:

[How to allow specific characters with OWASP HTML Sanitizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558471/how-to-allow-specific-characters-with-owasp-html-sanitizer/12610759#12610759)

Answer (score 0):

Along with using PreparedStatement, you must check your input provided by user, on your webpages.

So now you have 2 different checks.
1. On your web pages, which will reduce processing time.
2. If something passes your initial check then preparedstatement will make sure your query is parsed properly.

E.g User is searching some item..

User input is

```
' OR ITEM in (Select ITEM from SOME_TABLE) OR ITEM = ''
```

And you are building your SQL, by concatenating the strings, then it will make SQL command as

```
Select * from TABLE_X WHERE ITEM = '' OR ITEM in (Select ITEM from SOME_TABLE) OR ITEM = ''
```

So your DATABASE is hacked, but in other case PreparedStatement it will parse your query and  would not let make user to modify the SQL...